# Webpack nodejs lib getting an empty object

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

I have built a vanilla js lib (nodejs) for crawling a website ([cei-crawler](https://github.com/Menighin/cei-crawler)).

I'm using Webpack and Babel to bundle and transpile it. I had to introduce babel because Webpack was complaining with some features like `class fields`.

Thing is the minified bundled code simply doesn't work.
I try to `require` it and get an empty object.

Here is my `webpack.conf.js`:

```
const path = require('path');
const nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');

let config = {
  entry: './src/app.js',
  target: 'node',
  externals: [nodeExternals()],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: ['babel-loader']
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['*', '.js']
  },
  output: {
    filename: 'app.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
  }
};
module.exports = config;
```

and my `package.json` with the babel config:

```
{
  "name": "cei-crawler",
  // ...
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      "@babel/preset-env"
    ],
    "plugins": [
      "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties",
      "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime"
    ],
    "sourceType": "unambiguous"
  }
}
```

Then if I run `npm link` with the bundled code and try to use it I get an empty object:

```
const ceiCrawler = require('cei-crawler');
console.log(ceiCrawler); // {}
```

If I use `npm link` with the unbundled code, it works just fine.

Any ideas of what configuration am I missing?

Thanks!

Comment: I believe it must be something to do with configuring the output as `library`. Try out `library` and `libraryTarget` under `output`.

Comment: @AshishRanjan sorry for the late response. That did the trick! Thank you! If you want to make a reply out of this comment I will gladly accept it! :)